# Returning the ids from the object within the arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a multidimensional javascript array of objects that I am trying to use to simply collate the Unit id into a new array as shown below.

What is the best solution for returning the id within the inner value so I just get an array of the ids whatever I try seems to not work

```
[
  {
    units: [
      {
        id: 10000282,
        name: "Group 1",
      },
      {
        id: 10000340,
        name: "Group 2",
      },
      {
        id: 10000341,
        name: "Group 3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    units: [
      {
        id: 10000334,
        name: "Group 4",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Expected output - just return an array with simply the ids
e.g
 `ids = [ 10000282, 10000340, 10000341, 10000334 ]`

Comment: you can try `Array.prototype.reduce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that data is in variable `data`:

```
> data.map(o => o.units.map(u => u.id)).flat()
[ 10000282, 10000340, 10000341, 10000334 ]
```

This assumes you're in an environment [where `.flat()` is a thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

If that's not the case, the longer way around is

```
const ids = [];
data.forEach(o => {
   o.units.forEach(u => {
     ids.push(u.id);
   });
});
```